# Deauth attack - No such BSSID available

Tags: deauth-attack

When I was trying to do a deauth attack, I was getting an error even though I entered all the information correctly. However, when I add the `-D` parameter, this problem is solved. I don't fully understand the function of the `-D` parameter. Can anyone explain this in detail?

[image: Screenshot of aireplay-ng without the flag -D]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deauth attack waits for a beacon frame from the aceess point (AP) and then sends deauth packets.

In your case, aireplay is not receiving a beacon frame from the AP, this could be due to you listening at the wrong channel, not being in range of the AP or a typo in the BSSID.

According to the [official website](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=aireplay-ng), the parameter `-D` disables AP detection. Some modes will not proceed if the AP beacon is not heard. This disables this functionality.

To answer your question, when adding `-D`, it's working, since the part where aireplay normally waits for a beacon frame is getting skipped.